# multiple function calls inside ngClass

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to apply multiple classes using ng-class like

```
ng-class="func1();function2()"
```

This throws an error.

Do I have to write complete in one function only?

Can I not call two functions like above or any proper syntax to do the same.

Comment: can you write code of function1() and function2() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming both functions returns a class name, you should be able to do:

```
ng-class="func1() + ' ' + function2()"
```

However it does smell a little bit. I much rather prefer to set up a watcher to update `classes` property on scope (or on controller if you use controllerAs).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There's no reason to either. You shouldn't be composing functions like that in the view. The `ng-click` directive exists to call a scope method on click. It doesn't simply `eval()` the code between the quotes.

To get an idea as to why all you have to do is write your own directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" />
<my-directive complete="total(value, model)"></my-driective>

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  scope: {
    complete: '&'
  },
  link: function(scope) {
    // use your imagination
    scope.complete({value: 'hello'})
  }
})
```

Notice how the function call actually parses the parameters that are provided to it and provides only the value that it needs to provide to the scope.

In other words, make a wrapper function, your code will thank you.